# df shows negative values for used?

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-space-utilization

I have a CentOS 5.2 server and running `df -h` I get this:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      672G -551M  638G   0% /
/dev/hda1              99M   12M   82M  13% /boot
tmpfs                 2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
```

that space wasn't even near 10% usage the last time it showed a correct value. I'm at a loss with whats going on.

#### EDIT #1

Ok so I had to reboot the server because SSHD hanged up, I'm guessing it was related to this.

Some new info, after rebooting, `df -h` showed 12Gb used (2%), but if I run `du -hcs /` it shows 46Gb total, theres a big difference here.

#### EDIT #2

After about 15mins of uptime `df -h` is showing negative values again:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      672G  -24G  660G   -  /
```

#### EDIT #3

More info, ran a `fsck` and this is the output:

```
Checking all file systems.
  [/sbin/fsck.ext3 (1) -- /] fsck.ext3 -f -y /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes 
Pass 2: Checking directory structure 
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity 
Pass 4: Checking reference counts 
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
 /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00: 204158/181633024 files (1.3% non-contiguous), 9224806/181633024 blocks 
[/sbin/fsck.ext3 (1) -- /boot] fsck.ext3 -f -y /dev/hda1 
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes 
Pass 2: Checking directory structure 
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity 
Pass 4: Checking reference counts 
Pass 5: Checking group summary information 
/boot: 34/26104 files (5.9% non-contiguous), 15339/104388 blocks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a file system corruption. You should unmount the partition and run a fsck.
Check also the logs and the console for any file system errors.

Comment: so this logical group is mounted on /, is it possible to safely run a fsck without having physical access?

Comment: you have to stop all processes having files opened for writing and then remount / read-only. So you have to stop pretty everything. I would experiment this on a VM with the same OS installed. To mount the root file system read-only: `mount / -o remount,ro`. After you run the fsck with file system mounted read-only you have to remount it read-write and start the daemons, or better just reboot/reset.

Comment: i've ran fsck and from the output it doesn't seem anything is wrong, i'll update with the log

Comment: May be you have a hardware problem. Run a `memtest86+`. For this you will have to reboot the server. And the downtime will be a few good hours. Run other hardware tests... for CPU, etc... Check the temperatures on the server.

Answer (score 4):

I think this might mean that you have gone beyond what is reserved as a root only space (Default is 5% on ext3 I think):

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep -i 'Reserved block count'
Reserved block count:     1877194
```

Reserved block count is a certain amount of blocks that only the root user can use after the disk is almost full (This prevents a normal user from filling up the fs and causing things to break).  From `man tune2fs`:

> ```
>    -m reserved-blocks-percentage
> ```
>
> Set the percentage of the filesystem
>   which may only be allocated by
>   privileged processes.   Reserving some
>   number of filesystem blocks for use by
>   privileged processes is done to avoid
>   filesystem fragmentation, and to allow
>   system daemons, such  as  syslogd(8), 
>   to  continue  to function  correctly 
>   after  non-privileged  processes  are 
>   prevented  from writing to the
>   filesystem.  Normally, the default
>   percentage of reserved blocks is 5%.

So I think something is taking up space fast as the root user.  You can use `du -hcs /` and drill down from there to find where the files are that are using the space.  If you think it might be something creating large files, you could also use the `find` command.

Comment: Thanks, i've added additional info. I'm still trying to troubleshoot what's happening.